# go channel doesn't output the data it passed

Tags: go

i am new to go, and i was experimenting with channels and found out this.

```golang
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    fmt.Println("initialized channel")
    go receiver(c)
    go helper(c)

    for x := range c {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}

func helper(c chan int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    c <- 5
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    c <- 4
    close(c)
}

func receiver(c chan int) {
    for x := range c {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

The issue is even though i am sending two numbers only one number get printed in the console.

```
initialized channel
5
```

output

Comment: The program exits before the `receiver` function prints the value it received.  Use a [wait group](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to ensure that the`receiver` function completes before the program exits.

Comment: It's also strange that you read from the channel in receiver and the main function. A value is only read once from a channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behavior cannot be predicted. Sometimes your program would work, sometimes it won't. I have explained the code (with comments) where the problem is happening.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    fmt.Println("initialized channel")

    // This is a receiver receiving from c (spawned goroutine)
    go receiver(c)
    // This is a sender (spawned goroutine)
    go helper(c)

    // This is again a receiver receiving from c
    // NOTE: As reciever and helper are spawned in
    // separate goroutine, control eventually reaches
    // here.
    // Behaviour is unpredictable as sometimes the data
    // sent to the channel might be recieved here and
    // sometimes it might be recieved by the receiver function.
    for x := range c {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}

func helper(c chan int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    c <- 5
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    c <- 4

    // When this close is triggered, the receiver in main
    // could get exited as the signal to stop ranging is sent
    // using signal. Right after that the main function ends
    // such that data recieved by the receiver couldn't get
    // printed (sometimes it would work as well) i.e., main
    // exited right before fmt.Println(x) in receiver function.
    close(c)
}

func receiver(c chan int) {
    for x := range c {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

To fix it, you can try this. There are more possible solutions, but this is good enough. I have removed `time.Sleep` calls as they are not relevant to us and for brevity.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize the channel
    c := make(chan int)

    // Spawn a goroutine that sends data to the
    // channel. Also, it is expected from the sender
    // only to close the channel as it only knows
    // when then send stops. Send to a closed
    // channel would panic.
    go send(c)

    // As send is running asynchronously, control
    // reaches here i.e., the receiver. It ranges until
    // c is closed and is guaranteed to receive every
    // date sent to channel c and then exit.
    for x := range c {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}

// send data to c
func send(c chan int) {
    c <- 5
    c <- 4
    close(c)
}
```